# How to display default admin shares (C$) in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, network-shares

I have my network sharing set up so that when I go to `\\CompName\c$` I can get to the C: drive of the CompName computer.  However, if I navigate to `\\CompName\` directly, or via the network browser, I do not see the C$ drive in the list of available drives (unless I have specifically shared it on CompName and mapped it on the local computer).

I know it is possible for all of the default admin shares to be visible in the Windows Explorer drives list for each computer because my main computer used to do it.  However, somewhere in the midst of moving equipment around or formatting and reinstalling, the ability was lost.

All I'm finding in my Googling is how to get the shares to work (mine already are), not how to make them show up by default.

Answer (score 1):

Dollar signs hide your share - if you rename the share without the dollar sign (right click C: drive > properties > sharing > advanced sharing > share this folder > name it "C" > apply, you can also manage share permissions in this window - keep in mind share permissions are different from ntfs permissions), then it will show up in My Computer (aka Computer) when you UNC path to the server/pc alone.

However, for the C drive, I would recommend not showing everyone that it's shared out, but that's your call in the end.

Comment: Yep, I was aware that $ hid the share, and sharing out each drive is something I was trying to avoid doing (several desktops with multiple drives each).  Since I've had computers automatically display the hidden shares before, I was hoping to figure out how to do it again.  FWIW, $ only hides the shares for other Windows machines.  My Linux and Android devices can see all the shares by default.  Makes me think there is a setting (registry?) which is specific to the viewing machine, not the remote ones.

Comment: I am currently unaware of a registry edit that will automatically show them in My Computer/Computer, however you can use CMD (net view \\server /all)... I will take a peek for the registry mod you are looking for though.

Comment: I just want to mention that the search "list admin shares in explorer" now shows this page as #1 in Google for me...

Comment: Try your Google search from a friend's device and you're likely to get a different first search result.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/how-to-list-hidden-shares-remotely

This command will display all shares including hidden administrative shares, this works remotely as well as locally.

```
Net View \\server_name /all
```

Comment: Why should I click on that link, what is that exactly?